# c# using checkboxlist

Tags: c#, bots, checkboxlist

i have a script (simple log-in bot ) that tests my sites main sychel on all servers now since some of the servers are taken out of the pool i want to do a checkbox list of all servers and that the bot will run only on checked server names , so i want that the checked server will or just numbers will be inserted to an array or sting which ever is easier.
i am a noob in c# so if u can give examples ill apritiate it .
  label1.Text = string.Format("XXX{0}", i.ToString());

```
        try
        {
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            //int passwordnum = rnd.Next(1, 100);

            switch (step)
            {
                case 0:

                    this.webBrowser1.Navigate(string.Format("http://servername{0}.mysite.com:2323/mysite-sign-up/", i.ToString()));
                    step++;


                    break;
```

Comment: FYI: You need to expand your question and ask it properly. As it stands, I have no idea what the hell you've just said.

Comment: i want to create a checkboxlist with names of servers and that the names of servers will be inserted into a string or linked list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it 
int i = 0;
            List servers = new List();

```
        i = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count;


        foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            servers.Add(itemChecked.ToString());
```